# How to keep Django 2.2 migrations on Kubernetes while developing?

Tags: django, kubernetes, migration, kubernetes-pvc

I have a rather complex K8s environment that one of the Deployments is a Django application. Currently we are having a very hard time whenever I need to update a model that has already been migrated to a PostgreSQL database.

Let's say for instance that I create an application named Sample, that has a simple table on the models.py. My development process (skaffold) builds the docker and apply it locally on the minikube, after this is done I connect to the pod via `kubectl exec` and execute the `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`, so far so good.

After some time, let's say I need to create a new table on the models.py file of the Sample application, the skaffold builds the docker, kills the old pod, and create the new pod. So I connect as usual via `kubectl exec` and try to execute the `makemigrations` and `migrate` command, lo and behold, there's no migration to apply. And of course no change is made on the PostgreSQL.

Upon further searching this, I believe that the reason for this is that since the docker is built without the `Sample/migrations` folder, and there's already a table (the original one) on the PostgreSQL, when I run the `makemigrations` it creates only the `0001_initial.py` file, that has all the tables but, since the table already exists, when executing the `migrate`the django believes that the migration is already applied, therefore it won't apply.

If what I found out is true, how can I keep this files on a PVC, so that they are always kept between each pod recreation?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to commit your changes to the models.py and did add the new migration to your code repo.

Comment: makemigration should be run before commiting your changes, you should only run python manage.py migrate at every models update

Comment: @RedCricket, I haven't forgot to commit the changes, when I enter the pod I can see the models.py as inteded

Comment: @paltaa, this can be a little cumbersome, since we are on a team of around 10 developers, each working on different apps, is there no other way? From what I understood I need to execute the makemigrations BEFORE creating the docker, right? And keep this on the version control, is that correct?

Comment: Hello everyone, if this is the final answer (execute the makemigration before actually creating the docker), I'm going to have a very hard time orchestrating this with the other developers, specially when migrating to the production kubernetes. Is there any other way?